# Can't enter text from keyboard into a script editor window already containing code

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm using the latest script editor (rather than the legacy editor). No problem entering text from the keyboard into a newly created script file, but when I try to edit, say, Code.gs, already containing some code, the editor won't accept keyboard input (except Enter, Del) although it allows me to paste code from an external text file.

If I clear (CTRL+X) all the code I can then type into the script window. But pasting the code back reactivates the lock. I'm guessing this may be something to do with the built-in code validation, but I cannot see how to disable this behaviour. I'm embarrassed to have to ask this question. TIA.

Comment: It could be a bug in the new code editor.  If that's the case then you can create a new issue on the [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=823905)  But before you do that, I'd try to find which line is causing the problem.  I'd create a new "gs" file, and use that as a back up for your existing code.  Use CTRL+x to cut all the code out of code.gs, paste it into the new file, then cut half that code and paste it back into code.gs.  Keep cutting in half until you find the code causing the problem.

Comment: Can you show a screencast of the experienced behavior? Did you try to refresh the browser tab with the script editor?

Comment: I'm narrowing the problem down. At the top of Code.gs is an empty JS comment (// followed by a space). With that line present I cannot edit the first **ten** lines following, using the keyboard. When the comment line is removed I can edit without any problem. If I then add another comment line – say at line 16 - the next **4** lines can't be edited, the 10 lines following are okay, the code below that is again locked.

Anyway, this is too bizarrre a problem to spend further time on, so for now I'll just work around it.